# Will a 5V crystal oscillator oscillate with a 3.3V supply?

Tags: oscillator, crystal

My question is in the title. I was looking for a component, but I can only find it with 5V. There is no data sheet provided so my question is in general:

Will a 5V crystal oscillator oscillate with a 3.3V supply?

[Here is the component](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1-4-8-10-12-15-16-20-25-27MHz-Crystal-Oscillator-Osc-5V-H-DIP/181176601343?_trksid=p2047675.c100010.m2109&_trkparms=aid=555012&algo=PW.MBE&ao=1&asc=20887&meid=5873652114654548573&pid=100010&prg=9311&rk=1&rkt=24&sd=321140084566).

Comment: The shown data say 5V +/-5% so I would say that the part is for 5V operation only.

Comment: Will a gasoline engine run on diesel fuel? Maybe, but not very well, and not very long.

Comment: For all I know 5V could be the maximum rating since it is not explicitly stated, but I get the idea from the answer below and I will avoid using it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe. As in, it's not guaranteed to, but it's also not guaranteed not to.

And it might even do something really *devious*, like work when you are looking at it and not when you aren't.

Or you could get a bunch which work quite well and use them in prototypes, and then your contract manufacturer could get them from a different factory lot and they'd all fail to run in this out of spec condition.

In other words **don't do that** unless you plan to take over the manufacturing test/QA role usually performed by the part manufacturer.  For *extreme* applications where there are simply no parts with official specifications which meet the need, this *is* sometimes done, but it's hopefully done with full awareness of the risks and shift in responsibility.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and I understand why this is not recommended. I for sure do not want to add this kind of potential odd behavior etc.